# WP Meta Query - compare LIKE/IN serialized string to serialized array in database

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

I am trying to bring through content based on a unique GUID. The database is stored in a serialized array and this cannot be changed.

An example record would be:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:8:"16YL3332";}
```

And I currently use this in WP to serialize the string and run it in `get_posts` function using the following `args`

```
    $guid serialize(strval($_GET['guid'])); // var dump = string(15) "s:8:"16YL3332";"
    $args = array(
        "post_type" => "custom-post-type",
        "post_status" => "publish",
        "posts_per_page" => 1,
        "meta_query" => array( 
            "key" => "_fixtures",
            "value" => array($guid),
            "compare" => "LIKE"
        )
    );
```

I am having no success in bring the appropriate data back. WP defaults to bring back the most recent content published in the post type.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you casting the $guid variable to an array? I'm not sure that's needed. If you just pass it as `'value' => $guid`, does that work?

Also, see the following QA for some more information that may help you:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115833/how-do-i-search-an-array-stored-in-a-custom-field-using-wp-query

Comment: Hi Greg - no it doesn't just using the `guid` as a single variable

Comment: For what it's worth, I just noticed in your code posted above that there's no "=" sign in the line: `$guid serialize(strval($_GET['guid']));`.. it should probably be `$guid = serialize(strval($_GET['guid']));`